# HTML select options: setting the selected attribute to an input element has no effect

Tags: javascript, html

What I did is

```
var select  = document.createElement("select");
var option1 = document.createElement("option");
var option2 = document.createElement("option");
select.appendChild(option);
select.appendChild(option);
// Set values and texts here.
option2.selected = true;
```

The last line of code above has no effect, I still get `option1` as the selected option. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the `select` to the body. It also helps to add some text to the `option`s:

```js
var select  = document.createElement("select");
var option1 = document.createElement("option");
var option2 = document.createElement("option");
var option3 = document.createElement("option");
document.body.appendChild(select);
option1.innerText = 'One';
option2.innerText = 'Two';
option3.innerText = 'Three';
select.appendChild(option1);
select.appendChild(option2);
select.appendChild(option3);
option2.selected = true;
```

I also added a third option to show that `option2.selected = true` is respected

Answer (score 0):

Add the `value` & `innerHTML` property to the select. And also fix the typo

```js
var select = document.createElement("select");
var option1 = document.createElement("option");
var option2 = document.createElement("option");
option1.value = "1";
option1.innerHTML = "1";
option2.value = "2";
option2.innerHTML = "2";
option2.selected = true;

select.appendChild(option1);
select.appendChild(option2);
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(select)
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add "select[1].selected  =1;" into your code, please check the following code. this code worked for me.

```
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    //Create array of options to be added
    var array = ["Volvo","Saab","Mercades","Audi"];

    //Create and append select list
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
    myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

    //Create and append the options
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);
        option.text = array[i];
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
   selectList[2].selected  =1;
```